# Laravel 5.2 MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5

First my error was Class Input not found so i added

> 'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,

in aliases array

Now when i submit my form it gives this error

> ERROR:  MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:

**Routes.php**

```
Route::post('add', function () {
    $name = Input::get('name');
    if(DB::table('projects')->whereName($name)->first() != NULL) return 'already exist';
    DB::table('projects')->insert(array('name'=>'$name'));
    return Redirect::to('/add'); 
});
```

**welcome.blade.php :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Laravel Learning</title>
</head>
    <body>
            {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'add')) !!}
                {!! Form::text('name', 'Your Name...') !!}
                {!! Form::submit('Click Me!') !!}
            {!! Form::close() !!}   
    </body>
</html>
```

**Error Snap:**
[image]

Comment: Does the data get inserted, though? Since you also redirect to `return Redirect::to('/add');`, which will be a `GET` url.

Comment: Pass also the csrf_token

Comment: @Ciccio nopx I just see that error and nothing is inserted in DB!

Comment: @aldrin27 is that must ?

Comment: From the docs `If you use the Form::open method with POST, PUT or DELETE the CSRF token will be added to your forms as a hidden field automatically.`, so if you inspect your page source (in browser) I suspect that's already there.

Comment: @Ciccio yes you are right bro but can you please help me in the above problem.

Comment: @ngEngineer can you paste your routes.php here? You are defining /add with post and then within that there is a redirection to /add via get. Is there a route handler defined for get method as well?

Comment: @Manju no I am using redirect::to for redirecting back to /add route.There is no problem with that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to bring into practice of not using the routes.php to directly executing functions. meaning, the function used in the routes is suposed to be in a controller, maybe that is why laravel 5.1 isnt allowing you to perform the task.

to give you a better understanding of the workflow

**routes.php ->**

```
Route::resource('projects', 'projectController');
```

**welcome.blade.php ->**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Laravel Learning</title>
</head>
<body>
        {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'projects')) !!}
            {!! Form::text('name', 'Your Name...') !!}
            {!! Form::submit('Click Me!') !!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}   
</body>
</html>
```

**Then, go to your cmd, browse to your project folder, and fire up the command**

```
php artisan make:controller projectController
```

Here, the relevant functions you need will be automatically created for you, for ease of use of the functions, cool huh...

**Now write your add logic into the create function.**

```
public function store()
{
  Project::create(Request::all());
  //here you can write your return redirect(''); 
}
```

Also make sure you create a model. for example

**run command**

```
php artisan make:model Project
```

**inside the Project model ->**

```
protected $fillable = [
 'name'
];
```

the purpose of using this fillable array is for security purposes to avoid mass assignment vulnerability.

hope this helps you. feel free to ask questions